# JMeter working on Virtual machine

Tags: jmeter

Application is deployed in 16GBVM. While running JMeter from dedicated system throwing Network socket exception for 300 users
When i changed application to 8GB dedicated system its is working for 500 users trowing some other java exception.
Will JMeter support VM? Will get similar results(response time, throughput) like dedicated system.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter doesn't know anything about underlying software or hardware, it is pure Java application so its run inside [Java Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) which is an abstraction layer on top of OS which in its turn the abstraction layer on top of hardware.

So given VM and real device have similar hardware specifications you should get the similar results. Just make sure you following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), to wit:

- Run your test in non-GUI mode
- Disable all listeners during test run
- Use only those pre/post processors and assertions which are absolutely required
- [Tune Java Heap and Garbage Collection setting](https://dzone.com/articles/java-performance-tuning)s according to total amount of available physical RAM and your load pattern.

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for comprehensive information and some JMeter tuning tips.